# Balancing noise energy contributions with friction term

Tags: noise, stochastic-processes

I'm looking for a result that would say something about the way in which to pick a proper constant $\sigma$ in generic models of the form:
$$ \ddot{x} = - \gamma \dot{x} - \nabla V(x) + \sigma \xi(t) $$
for potential of type $$ V(x) =\frac{k}{n} x^n$$ where $\xi(t)$ is some noise kind of noise (I'm mostly interested in Gaussian white noise, Ornstein-Uhlenbeck and Dichotomous noise)

I know the results for special case of $n=2$, but is there perhaps some general recipe by which one can easily obtain the constant $\sigma$, such that energy in a given model is conserved?

Comment: I'm curious, how do you pick $\sigma$ to keep energy conserved in the $n=2$ case? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Is this question about the fluctuation-dissipation theorem or something else entirely?

Comment: @DanielSank I think I saw it in Risken - it's stochastic thermodynamics of harmonic oscillator... now giving it a second thought it might have been $V(x)=0$, but nevertheless the question stays the same.

Comment: @alarge not at all, I'm just asking whether there's a result that allows me to create a general setup in which I do not pump any energy to the system.